# Service Method Not Called When Implementing IDisbatchMethodInspector

Tags: wcf

I am extending the WCF pipeline for a set of service methods through (1) a class derived from BehaviorExtensionElement implementing IDispatchMessageInspector and (2) a class, set through an attribute applied to the service method's interface method definition, implementing IDispatchMessageFormatter.

I am able to get each configured and functioning individually, however when configured to work together after processing the message in IDispratchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest the method IDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest is never called.  However, it is called when I remove the configuration for the behavior my configuration file.  Ideally, I'd have both custom classes running as part of the pipeline and working together.

Any suggestions on what the issue may be or ideas as to how I can debug further?

I am happy to provide more specifics and simplified code.

Cheers,
Denise